# Is it possible to disable fuzzy searching in Sublime Text 3?

Tags: sublimetext3, sublimetext

I don't like the fuzzy search feature that's present across Sublime Text 3. Is it possible to disable it completely and stay with either:

- regular search,
- or multi-term search in an AND fashion?

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible, no. The only options available are to use fuzzy matching to narrow in on what you want, or scroll through the list of items to pick the one you want.

Although there's not a regular search, the fuzzy search is inherently an `AND` search if you enter two or more terms separated by whitespace, though. For example entering `ind` shows you all terms containing that term (say all of the `index.html` files or such), and `ind con` and `con ind` (order doesn't matter) would use both terms to further narrow down, such as all `index.html` files in a folder named `controller`.